# Apple store acceptence, downloading layout hints to iphone allowed?

Tags: iphone, ios

Apple says this can be a reason for rejection for any Iphone app:

*No Interpreted Code
You cannot create an app that downloads and executes code that was not present in the app bundle submitted to Apple.*

So that means downloading Html code from my webservice to give some style to my app is not allowed?

Also other than Html do you think it s allowed that I can download layout hints from a web service? for instance I have a dynamic questionarry to be downloaded from web service and every question has its own layout e.g the textboxes width and layout, which control to use (datepicker or textbox)..so app will look different than they accept in the app store. is this allowed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's submission policies, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML isnt [Interpreted code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) (the ml stands for Markup Language). I suspect downloading html isnt why you failed verification.

Comment: 2 different answers, are you sure about this answer? because I change my app's looks after it has been approved by the store?

Answer (score 0):

No because downloading code in any form is prohibited according to http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
They don't want the application to change behaviour once it is released.

Comment: sending layout hints are not allowed? texbox width, alignment of input controls..etc?